# Use ngrepeat on Set

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a `vm.s = new Set([1,2,3])`

how can I use `ngRepeat` on `s` without convert it to array?

I have tried

```
<option ng-repeat="o in vm.s">{{o}}</option>
<option ng-repeat="o in vm.s.values()">{{o}}</option>
<option ng-repeat="o in Array.from(vm.s)">{{o}}</option>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set() is a EMCAScript 6 feature. Angular 1.x doesn't support ES6 features directly that way. `Array.from(vm.s)` should work for you.

Comment: correct, and I think it's the same reason that I can't call `Array.from(someSetObject)` in html(the 3rd option in my question)

Comment: @pledez Angular do not allow writing global variables in angular expression (due to their stupid complete-insecure "sandbox"). you may write `[].constructor.from(vm.s)` if you don't mind its ugly. otherwise, this had to be done in controller...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to convert Set to array at the controller using:

```
 Array.from(vm.s.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its working, You have to convert set to array using , `vm.arr = Array.from(vm.s);`

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.arr = [];
  vm.s = new Set([1,2,3]);
   vm.arr = Array.from(vm.s);
  console.log(vm.arr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="o in main.arr">{{o}}</li>
     </ul>
  </body>
```